# Car Search java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, search, binary-search

In one of my classes we created a program that randomly creates  10 cars with the price and star rating. Right now the program creates the 10 objects and then creates another object that it compare the 10 to. It searches by the star rating, sorts the 10 by star rating, then runs a binary search on the 10 objects. I have been trying to improve on it by adding in the car manufacturer name to each object but keep messing up the program. The program has two classes

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Sorter{
    static Car [] ary; // declare
    final static int NUM_CARS = 10;
    public static void main() {
        //Scanner rating = new Scanner(System.in);
        //int r = rating.nextInt();
        Car key = new Car();
        ary = new Car[NUM_CARS]; // initialize
        int i;
        int position;
        for (i=0; i<NUM_CARS; i++) {
            ary [ i ] = new Car();
        }
        System.out.println("Unsorted:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ary));
        System.out.println("Sequential search for " + key);
        ary[0].reset();
        position = sequentialSearch(key)+1; //add one to the index position to display the position on screen that the user's desired search is first found
        System.out.println("Total comparisons: " 
            + ary[0].getAllCount());
        System.out.println("Found a position: " +position);

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Sorted:");
        ary[0].reset();
        Arrays.sort(ary);
        System.out.println("Total comparisons: " 
            + ary[0].getAllCount());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ary));
        System.out.println("Binary search for " + key);
        ary[0].reset();
        position = binarySearch(key)+1; //add one to the index position to display the position on screen that the user's desired search is first found
        System.out.println("Found a position: " +position);
        System.out.println("Total comparisons: " 
            + ary[0].getAllCount());
    }

    public static int binarySearch (Car keyCar) {
        return Arrays.binarySearch(ary,keyCar);
    }
    public static int sequentialSearch (Car keyCar) {
        int pos = -1;
        int i;
        int answer;
        for (i=0; i<ary.length; i++) {
            answer = ary[i].compareTo(keyCar); 
            if (answer==0) {
                pos = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return pos;
    }
}
```

Second class

```
import java.util.*;
/**
 * in class work
 */
public class Car implements Comparable<Car> {
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    int stars;
    double price;
    String name [] = {"Ford", "Dodge", "Chevrolet", "Honda", "Toyota", "VW", "Hyundai"};
    int  myCounter;
    static int allCounter;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Sorter
     */
    public Car() {
        Random generator = new Random ();
        price = generator.nextDouble()*50000 + 50000;

        stars = generator.nextInt(5)+1;
        reset();
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("$%,7.0f(%d stars)",price,stars);
        //$ put dollar sign infront
        //up to 7 digits
        //, puts commas
    }
    /**
     * Resets counter to zero
     */
    public void reset(){
        myCounter=0;
        allCounter=0;
    }
    public int getMyCount() {
        return myCounter;
    }
    public int getAllCount() {
        return allCounter;
    }
    /**
     * @param  other A house to compare to.
     * @return  Returns 0 if they are equal
     */
    public int compareTo(Car other)
    {
        myCounter++;
        allCounter++;
        if (this.stars < other.stars) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.stars> other.stars) {
            return +1;
        }
        return 0; // equals
    }
}
```

How do I make it so that the objects will display the price, star rating, and the manufacturer? 
Also, another thing I'd like to do but haven't tried yet is making it so the user can input what star rating they want and it'll display those cars only. This part is the next thing I'd like to try when time comes around to do so.

Comment: I haven't tried a whole lot of different things because I'm not sure of what code to even use. 
In public Car() i tried putting

name = generator.nextLine(name.length);

but it said "can not find symbol"

Comment: Put details of what you tried, in the question itself.

Comment: @TrippKinetics sorry I'm new to this site so I hit enter to skip a line but it posted it.

Answer (score 1):

To associate data with an object, a variable to store that data needs to be in the object's constructor. So, to associate a manufacturer with each car object, you'll have to add `String manufacturer` or something similar as a variable in your Car class's constructor. It seems like you would then want to set that `manufacturer` variable to a random element of your `String name []` array.

To make the car "display" the `manufacturer` variable you just created, you would have to modify the `toString()` method in your car class to print `manufacturer` as well as `price` and `stars`.